# react-native-video: Cannot read property 'Constants' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-video

I am trying to include a YouTube video in my react native project. Since I already tried [react-native-youtube](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube) and did not work at all I tried installing [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video).

However, I am getting the following error:
[image]

I tried: 
deleting my node_modules and npm i again followed by react-native link and react-native link react-native-video. Several times.

My package.json:

[image]

Comment: your source? `<Video />` component parameters? .... from source `    const RCTVideoInstance = this.getViewManagerConfig('RCTVideo');` fails

Comment: This is happening to me on android too, any help?

Answer (score 2):

For Android using `Expo` and `EAS Build` I just ran

```
eas build --profile development --platform android
```

This fixed my issue

I assume with pure `React Native` too you just need to rebuild the App.

Comment: Yes Sizo in React Native with Rebuild it works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

react-native: 0.63.4:
the problem is with linking, the issue got fixed by following these steps:

- -removing the Pods folder from the ios folder:
- -removing the node modules
- -removing the build using this command: rm -rf ios/build
- -running Yarn to reinstall the packages
- -installing Pods using this command: cd ios && pod install --repo-update && cd ..
- -running the ios build
- -starting react native and removing the cache with this command: yarn start --reset-cache

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

- react-native link
- cd ios && pod install
- check in podfile that react-native-video is added or not.
- If not add it manually and run pod install.
- then in xcode build Phases check search video , if you found video package already added then run app and check.
- otherwise add it manually in Link Binary with Libraries.
- and run app.

Comment: And for android?

Answer (score 0):

for me it was closing the metro window (I switched from project with react-native-video to a project with expo-av)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was downloading packages with npm. I had installed expo-CLI and was downloading packages for react-native CLI. There's some cross package error i guess however if you're using expoCLI and missed this by mistake you can clean node_modules remove package-lock.json and use expo-video.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/video/
or
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-video-player

`npm i expo-video-player`